# Error: Cannot find module './linters/rubocop'

Tags: npm

I am trying to execute the command `npm run lint` ("npx lint "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}" --quiet --fix") but I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module './linters/rubocop'  Require stack:
>
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lint/utils/linter.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lint/index.js  at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)  at Function.Module._load
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)  at Module.require
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)  at require
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)  at Object.
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lint/utils/linter.js:50:5)  at
>   Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)  at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)  at Module.load
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)  at Function.Module._load
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)  at Module.require
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19) {  code:
>   'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: [
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lint/utils/linter.js',
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lint/index.js'

I have installed:

> - npm 8.10.0
> - nodejs v16.20
> - angular CLi 14.2.11

And this is my package.json

[package.json](https://github.com/GOrtiz16/npm/blob/main/package.json)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `npx` and change `lint` to `eslint`.

```json
  "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}\" --quiet --fix",
  "lint:fix": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}\" --fix ",
  "prettier": "pretty-quick --staged && eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}\" --fix"
```